# Force ASP.NET WebAPI To Restart itself

Tags: asp.net-web-api

We have an asp.net web application which can take in extra features by hot loading DLL's. One of the issues with this is that these DLL's may be updated while the application is running. Is there a way to issue a request to the app to restart itself, thus unloading the DLL's from the app domain and picking up the new DLL's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you need is

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

It Terminates the current application. The application restarts the next time a request is received for it.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain.aspx) link

Comment: one thing to point, is that it will not work for self hosted Web API